# Обратный вызов callback

Tags: android, callback

У меня есть два класса: `CustomDialog` и `CustomPreference`.
Из `CustomPreference` вызывается диалоговое окно, которое создается в `CustomDialog`.
Нужно, чтоб при нажатии кнопки `"Ок"` значение из `EditText'a` диалога менялось в `CustomPreference`.

Пробовал сделать так, но при нажатии `Ок` приложение вылетает.... Подскажите, почему?

CustomPreference:

```
package com.lar1ch.test;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import androidx.appcompat.app.*;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.res.*;

public class CustomPreference extends LinearLayout implements CustomDialog.DialogClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void dialogOkClick(int changedValue)
    {
        setValue(changedValue);
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }



    private TextView title;
    private TextView value;
    private String mTitle;
    private int mValue;

    public CustomPreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }


    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setView(context);
        parseAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setView(final Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.pref_layout, this);
        this.title = findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.value = findViewById(R.id.value);

        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1) {
                    CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
                    dialog.showDialog(context, mTitle, mValue);
                }
            });
    }

    private void parseAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
        if (a != null) {
            mTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomView_android_title);
            setTitle(mTitle);
            mValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomView_android_defaultValue, 0);
            setValue(mValue);
        }
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        this.title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        mValue = value;
        this.value.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

}
```

CustomDialog:

```
package com.lar1ch.test;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import androidx.appcompat.app.*;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class  CustomDialog {
    public interface DialogClickListener
    {
        public void dialogOkClick(int changedValue);
    }
    DialogClickListener mListener;
    public void setListener(DialogClickListener listener)
    {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }
    public void showDialog(final Context context, String title, int value)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        setListener(mListener);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        adb.setView(mView);
        final EditText etCustomDialog = mView.findViewById(R.id.customdialogEt);
        etCustomDialog.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        etCustomDialog.setSelection(etCustomDialog.getText().length());
        if(title == null)
        {
            title = "Dialog";
        }
        adb.setTitle(title);
        adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        adb.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {
                    int newValue = Integer.parseInt(etCustomDialog.getText().toString());
                    mListener.dialogOkClick(newValue);
                }


        });
        adb.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {
                }


        });
        adb.setNeutralButton(R.string.default_value, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {
                }


        });
        adb.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите лог ошибки и на какой строке она возникает.

Comment: 11-06 20:59:11.737 E/AndroidRuntime(5543): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.lar1ch.test.CustomDialog$DialogClickListener.dialogOkClick(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Ну, видимо у вас `mListener` - `null`. Возможно, вы забыли его инициализировать

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну... У вас в классе есть сеттер для слушателя - вы его вызываете?

Comment: Нет, он остался от предыдущих попыток... В какой момент его вызывать, перед mListener.dialogOkClick(newValue);? В общем, я много вариантов пробовал просто... Можно пример callback'a, который будет работать?

Comment: Нет, вам это нужно, скорее всего, вызвать там, где вы создаёте экземпляр `CustomDialog `

Comment: Сложность в том, что у вас может быть проблема сразу в нескольких местах по нескольким причинам. Может вы забыли метод где-то вызвать, а может у вас проблемы из-за жизненного цикла активити/фрагмента/диалога.

Comment: Вы таки попробовали сделать то, что я предлагал  выше?

Comment: Всё, разобрался) добавил dialog.setListener(CustomPreference.this) перед dialog.showDialog(context, mTitle, mValue). Спасибо большое)